# How to make unique constraint shared with field from another table in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

There are several tables referring to each other, for example:

```
appointment
-----------
id
name
department_id

department
----------
id
name
company_id

company
-------
id
name


people
------
id
name
appointment_id
personnel (string)

UniqueConstraint(personnel, company_id)
```

People must have a unique personnel number within the company. Since appointment refers to department and it refers to the company. I theoretically know company_id for people table, but unique references do not work between tables for postgres. Is it possible to redesign these structures to meet the uniqueness requirement?

Answer (score 1):

The only data model I can think of is to add redundant copies of `company_id`:

```
ALTER TABLE appointment
   ADD company_id bigint NOT NULL;

-- redundant, but required as target for the foreign key
ALTER TABLE department
   ADD UNIQUE (company_id, id);

ALTER TABLE appointment
   ADD FOREIGN KEY (company_id, department_id) REFERENCES (company_id, id);

ALTER TABLE people
   ADD company_id bigint NOT NULL;

-- redundant, but required as target for the foreign key
ALTER TABLE appointment
   ADD UNIQUE (company_id, id);

ALTER TABLE people
   ADD FOREIGN KEY (company_id, appointment_id) REFERENCES appointment (company_id, id);
```

Now you can have your constraint:

```
ALTER TABLE people
   ADD UNIQUE (personnel, company_id);
```

All these extra constraints won't be great for performance.

---

In practice, a better solution is to add a column `company_id` ob `people` and define triggers on all tables that make sure that any changes in the relationship automatically adapt the `company_id` column of `people`.

Writing these triggers correctly will take a little effort, and they also won't boost performance.